# Using conditionals with the arguments in argv

Tags: c, arguments, argv, conditional-statements

im trying to take the arguments in argv and use conditionals in them, for example

the entry of the program will be like this

./program -t  -d  -m

i want to do something like this
     if  == -t then in a variable save the value of the number 
     if  == -d then in a variable save the value of the string

i want to do this because the entry of the program can be like this

```
   ./program -d <string> -m <char> -t <number>
   ./program -m <char> -d <string>  -t <number>
```

how can i do this? i was trying to use getopt but i didnt understand it

Comment: `getopt` is certainly the easier way to go. Otherwise, you can just use `strcmp` to check if two strings are equal.

Comment: What about `getopt` was giving you trouble? I found [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) to be a pretty good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of how to handle a few short options is always a balance between a quick `strcmp` or `getopt` use as mentioned above. For a few options, there is nothing wrong with `strcmp`. Here is a quick example of using `strcmp` using your options:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 7) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error, insufficient input.\n  Usage: %s -d <string> -m <char> -t <int>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int it;
    char *str = NULL;
    char chr;
    int  num;

    for (it = 1; it < argc; it++) {
        if (strcmp ("-d", argv[it]) == 0 && it < (argc - 1))
            str = strdup (argv[it+1]);
        if (strcmp ("-m", argv[it]) == 0 && it < (argc - 1))
            chr = *argv[it+1];
        if (strcmp ("-t", argv[it]) == 0 && it < (argc - 1))
            num = atoi (argv[it+1]);
    }

    printf ("\nOptions entered:\n\n");
    printf ("  str: %s\n  chr: %c\n  num: %d\n\n", str, chr, num);

    return 0;
}
```

**compile:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/opts opts.c
```

**run:**

```
$ ./bin/opts -d "this is my string" -m c -t 2048
```

**output:**

```
Options entered:

  str: this is my string
  chr: c
  num: 2048
```